# Process a subset of my dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a simple project where I'd like to unjar a subset of my dependencies and pack them into the output jar.

I have the two configurations:

```
configurations {
  embed   
  all
}

dependencies {
    embed group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    ...

    all embed
    all group: 'something-not-embeddable', name: 'dontembed'
    compile all
}
```

According to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html 50.5 Working with Dependencies section's example it should work.

In a later section of my build, I want to unjar the `embed` jars and use them as source for `jar`.

My problem is that the gradle output says:

```
> Could not find method all() for arguments [configuration ':embed'] on root project 'myproject'.
```

Can you tell me why my approach is not working and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Lol, looks like I chose a bad configuration name, works with `alldeps` instead of `all`

Comment: `all` conflicts with the `configurations.all` property. In other words , your code isn't actually adding a configuration named `all`, which is why you can't later refer to it in the `dependencies` block.